# how to alert browser from javaclass? is it possible? 

Tags: java, javascript

my scenario is that when ever my target is achieve i want to show alert in browser.
while target was checked in javaclass side...

i have a method in javascript like.

```
function targetAchieve(head,target,price)
{  
alert(head+"  Target Achieve"+"\n"+"Price:"+price+"\n"+"target: "+target+" \n"  );
}
```

i want call this method from my java class

```
ltp = MOConstants.round(ltp, 2);

if(ltp>=target){
    " here i want to call javascript's method"
}
```

thanks in advance...

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. JavaScript runs (most often) in the browser, while Java runs on the server (or do you have a Java Applet?). You cannot call JavaScript code that should be run in the browser directly from the server.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As far as I know **No** its not possible. And even if its possible you should not do it. Don't mix client side and server side coding.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [DWR](http://directwebremoting.org/dwr/index.html) to make remote calls from a Java web server to a client browser.

Comment: using DWR you can call java method from javascript. I think he needs reverse.

Comment: With DWR you can make calls either way. For server to client it offers Comet and other solutions.

Comment: but how can i implement DWR in my scenario?

Answer (score 0):

you cant do so like this

just make ajax call and check for update at regular interval and do your action

Answer (score 0):

I think you better do **polling** at some interval for your alerts. Create a separate `servlet` that handles only polling requests.
Or use web socket.
http://jwebsocket.org/?gclid=CPHkwKaGsKgCFcZ56wodkVsoHA
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets

Thanx.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use JSP page to display your content, you can call your java method to check whether you have achieved the target, and then display the your javascript method.

Ex:
<%
 boolean isTargetArchievd = new ClassName().isTargetArchievd();
 String javascriptMethod = "";
 if(isTargetArchievd){
   javascriptMethod = "targetAchieve()";
 }
%>

//Inside your javascript 
<%= javascriptMethod %>